# Can Time Varying Coefficient models with a Kalman filter approximate any non-linear function?

Tags: time-series, nonparametric, time-varying-covariate

I read that Time Varying Coefficients (TVC) models with non-parametric methods can approximate any non-linear function. This is from  ["Non-Linear Models: Where Do We Go Next - Time Varying Parameter Models?"](https://doi.org/10.2202/1558-3708.1639) by Granger. It particularly mentions using a Kalman filter for this. However, I read that the Kalman filter is only good for linear models!

Now, it's reasonable that TVC can approximate any non-linear function, but what kind of non-parametric methods help maintain this promise? Why a Kalman filter? Is this just a guess?

1. Extra: Why not a non-parametric method like splines, since they work well with non-linearity?
2. Extra: It would be nice if there's a paper/book that address this.